# Delete from Multiple Tables using db_delete()

Tags: 7, database

How can we delete fields from multiple tables using [`db_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_delete/7) and `INNER JOIN` in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 11):

You can't I'm afraid.

[`db_delete()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_delete/7) takes a single string parameter to define which table the query is to be run against. There's no scope to provide more than one table at a time.

You can run any SQL statement you like, though, with [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7), eg.

```
// Deletes all nodes and related author users...please don't actually run this!!
$sql = 'DELETE u, n FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {users} u ON u.uid = n.uid';
db_query($sql);
```

Comment: That `db_delete` takes a single parameter, without allowing an alias, is annoying. Otherwise, it would be possible to use JOINs similar to db_select.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, db_delete takes a single parameter. You have to call `db_delete()` multiple times to delete data from multiple tables. Please see the following sample code:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_delete().
 */
function block_menu_delete($menu) {
  db_delete('block')
    ->condition('module', 'menu')
    ->condition('delta', $menu['menu_name'])
    ->execute();
  db_delete('block_role')
    ->condition('module', 'menu')
    ->condition('delta', $menu['menu_name'])
    ->execute();
}
```

Source link: 
https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/modules/block/block.module
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.module/7.x