# how to do a conditional subquery with db_delete

Tags: database

I currently am deleting by a manually constructed query, but there should be a better way to do this.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM {$table1} ";
$query .= "WHERE col1 = '$col1' ";
$query .= "AND table2_id in ";
$query .= "( SELECT id from {$table2} where col2=$col2 )";
db_query($query)->execute();
```

How do I do this using db_delete?

Table2 has a covering index, so this should be done in one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your current way is that fine for multiple table handle like that. From this [Delete from Multiple Tables using db_delete](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30718/delete-from-multiple-tables-using-db-delete) link you can see that:

[db_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_delete/7) takes a single string parameter to define which table the query is to be run against. There's no scope to provide more than one table at a time.